# How to determine optimal allocation size for JPA Sequence generator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, sequence

we have an entity with around 1000 insert per minute and have a TABLE generator configuration:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "someGenerator", strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@TableGenerator(name = "someGenerator", pkColumnValue = "gu_someEntity", valueColumnName = "sequence_next_hi_value")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

It works and due to previous limitations we weren't able to use SEQUENCE generator. Now I would like to change that to:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "someGenerator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "someGenerator", sequenceName = "gu_TestSequence", allocationSize = 50)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

JPA assigns a default allocation size of 50, which I included here. I wonder if we should have a larger value? We have 1000 inserts per minute with a single transaction inserting more than 10 being rare, so a single unit of work won't be needing a lot of ids.

We are using Hibernate with the **pool** sequence optimizer.